# HTML form posted but array returned is empty

Tags: php, html

I am trying to does an HTTP POST but the array returned from the post is empty which it shouldn't.

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_POST);  -->This is empty which it should NOT.
```

---

```
<form action="login/" class="form-horizontal well" id="login-form" method=
"post" name="login-form">
    <div class="span4 center">
        <input class="text-field input-block-level" id="email" name="email"
        placeholder="E-mail" size="30" type="email">
    </div>

    <div class="span4 center">
        <input class="text-field input-block-level" id="password" name=
        "password" placeholder="**********" size="20" type="password">
    </div><br>
    <br>

    <div class="span4 center">
        <input class="button-primary button-large" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is your form is redirected completely? I ask like this because i think in action you need to add **login.php** with php extension

Comment: Can you please define completely?

Comment: @user1688346 What happens when you post? Do you end up at `yoururl/login`, or somewhere else?

Comment: it ends up at myurl/login

Comment: The `myurl/login` is a directory which has `index.php` file in it with the `var_dump($_POST);`? Or do you use `mod_rewrite`? What's the contents of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ACTION` attribute tells the form where to `POST` the data to. if there's no such location as `login/`, the form will fail.

It should be:

```
<form class="form-horizontal well" method="post" action="yourlogincheck.php" id="login-form" name="login-form">
```

But it's perfectly fine to post to `login/` if your file structure is as follows:

- `file.php`
- `login/index.php`

In all other cases, it will fail. Also, make sure to add the trailing slash. It is important.

If it's `POST`'d correctly, you should get something like this with `var_dump`:

```
array(2) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(11) "foo@bar.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(7) "hunter2"
}
array(2) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(11) "foo@bar.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(7) "hunter2"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the POST to the login page. Send the `action` to the page that checks if they exist

Answer (score 1):

If your login.php in same directory than please set as per below other wise please set path in action and check it

```
<form action="login.php" class="form-horizontal well" id="login-form" method=
"post" name="login-form">
   your html code here
</form>
```

I hope this helps you